# Why doesn't the Python process show network usage?

Tags: python, windows, bandwidth, process-management

I am currently coding a program that is pretty network intensive (100+ requests per second). As I do not have a large internet bandwidth I was interested on how much of the bandwidth the program actually takes, so I decided to take a look at task management:

[image]

However it shows 0 Mbps... I am 100% sure that **at least** 2 Megabits per second are used.

Why doesn't task management display the internet usage? Is it because of the Python shell itself or because of Windows 10?

Edit: for some odd reason I do see it now... [image]

Comment: You're looking at IDLE's main pythonw.exe instance. Scripts run in a child process.

Comment: @eryksun I just checked again and suddenly it did show the Mbps (on the pythonw shell process)

Comment: There are at least two pythonw instances; one is running the IDLE application (it has 2 windows in your screenshot), and the other is running your script.